# how to find elements present in all three lists (most eficiently)

Tags: c#, algorithm, dictionary

I use C# and I have three `List<int>` (say of equal size n and of distinct elements). My goal is to find elements present in all three. So I could iterate through first one and check if item is in the other two. That would be O(n^2). I could sort the other two lists first and then check for item in them using binary search. That would be O(nlogn) (without sorting). 
Or I could construct two dictionaries `Dictionary<int, byte>`, where the key would be my list's item and then checking for an item would be O(1) and the total O(n). But how about the price of constructing dictionary? Can anyone tell how much does that cost?

Also perhaps there is even more efficient algorithm?

Comment: Does these lists contain elements in some order or they are unordered?

Comment: HashSet<int> has some benefits for this task.

Comment: The `HashSet` or LINQ solution is clearly the better way to go. If you were to sort the lists, you wouldn't do a binary search, but rather do a 3-way merge and keep only the items with duplicates. That would be O(n log n) to sort, and O(n log 3) to merge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a `HashSet` is fairly simple, and I think it will be your best bet for performance.

```
HashSet<T> hset = new HashSet<T>(list1);
hset.IntersectWith(list2);
hset.IntersectWith(list3);
return hset.ToList(); // skip the ToList() if you don't explicitly need a List
```

Comment: Or, to simplify with LINQ: `var rslt = list1.Intersect(list2).Intersect(list3).ToList();`

Comment: I thought of that too, but I figured the explicit `HashSet` would be at least as fast.

Comment: The `HashSet` solution might be marginally faster, although LINQ will use a `HashSet` (or equivalent) internally. I find the LINQ version somewhat easier to understand. And, it helps that it's easier to type. It mostly comes down to a matter of style.

Answer (score 1):

You could use only one `Dictionary<int, byte>` where value of `byte` could be 1 or 2. For first list you just do the insert with value equal to 1, and for second list you do `TryGetValue` and based on result do either insert or update with value equal to 2. For third list you check if value is 2.